# Printing a second subtitle in the middle of a frame in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I'd like to print a second subtitle in the middle of a frame in Beamer.

I tried using some macros used in the [source of Beamer](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbaselocalstructure.sty) but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the subtitle font and colour you could simply fake it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\framesubtitle{subtitle}

text

{\hskip-1.75em\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle} another subtitle}

text

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]