# How can I create boxes like the frametitle and framesubtitle in the middle of a frame?

Tags: beamer, sectioning, block, box

I am preparing a lecture note in `beamer`. I want to make headings in the middle of the frame which should look like `frametitle` or `framesubtitle` boxes. In the following MWE, I am using a `block` to create it, but I want the block body to be empty. How do I achieve this?

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,10pt, notheorems]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=magenta}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{bg=black}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Frame title}{Frame subtitle}
        Proof of a theorem ends here. Title heading for the next section should appear in the following box.
        \begin{block}{This box should look like frame title box}
        \end{block}
        Title heading for the next subsection should appear in the following box.
        \begin{block}{This box should look like frame subtitle box}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

PS: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374788/162028) did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can lookup the definition by searching where your `frametitle` template gets defined. For the theme `CambridgeUS` you will find, that it uses `beamerouterthemedefault.sty` and hence you can borrow the definition of the `beamercolorbox` from there and strip it of everything that is only used in the special purpose of a frametitle. Then you can easily use it in your MWE like this:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,10pt, notheorems]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=magenta}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{bg=black}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame title}{Frame subtitle}
    Proof of a theorem ends here. Title heading for the next section should appear in the following box.

\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,left,wd=\textwidth]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
    \strut This box should look like frame title box \strut\par%
    {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}This box should look like frame subtitle box\strut\par}%
    \vskip-1ex%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image]

---

If you want a box of full paper width and with the text split in two parts, here we go:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,10pt, notheorems]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=magenta}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{bg=black}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame title}{Frame subtitle}
    Proof of a theorem ends here. Title heading for the next section should appear in the following box.

\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,left,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
    \strut This box should look like frame title box \strut\par%
    \vskip-1ex%
\end{beamercolorbox}%

\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,left,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
    {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}This box should look like frame subtitle box\strut\par}%
    \vskip-1ex%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. A couple of issues here. The width of the box is not completely as the original one. I tried replacing `\textwidth` by `\framewidth` without a fruitful result. Secondly, I actually wanted separate boxes for `frametitle` and `framesubtitle` (in your answer `framesubtitle` box comes with `frametitle` always). Then learning from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375937/162028) I commented out `\strut This box should look like frame title box \strut\par` and that gives me my desired result.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul you are welcome, I added a modified code, can you check if this is what you anticipated?